# Get the underlying variable of an enum

Tags: rust

My simplified code:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A(u32),
    B(String),
    C(i32),
}

pub struct MyStruct {
    aa: String,
    bb: u16,
    my_enum: MyEnum,
}

let my_struct1 = MyStruct { /*...*/ };
```

How can I get the underlying variable of `my_struct1.my_enum` which could be a `u32`, `String` or `i32`. Is it only by pattern matching?

Comment: [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) covers these topics: [enums](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/enums.html), [`match`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/match.html), and [patterns](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/patterns.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching is not limited to `match`. If you only care about one type of the variant, you can also do

```
if let MyEnum::B(s) = my_struct1.my_enum {
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

The `println` line will only be run when the value of `my_struct1.my_enum` is actually of type `MyEnum::B`. Rust `enum` is safe. It is not like C `union`, which you can unsafely access the underlying value as you wish no matter which type the value actually is.

Comment: if they all had the same underlying type, say, u32 like A does, how would get that variable?

Comment: @OskarK. Then you will need to use `match`: `let v = match my_struct1.my_enum { MyEnum::A(a) => a, MyEnum::B(b) => b, MyEnum::C(c) => c };`.